# How does my WAP manage DHCP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, wireless-access-point

This is a curiosity question, because search queries similar to my question haven't yielded much. I am perhaps searching for the wrong terminology. I've always had multi-functional routers with wireless built in. I bricked my last one and ended up getting a router and WAP separately as a replacement. I am confused about how the addressing in this new network is actually managed.

The WAP must have a DHCP service on it. But the router does as well. As far as the router is concerned, the WAP (issued addr `192.168.1.38`, connected on `eth1`) is just another client connected by ethernet, correct? It has no clue it's an access point. Then when I connect to the WAP with a client I'm issued an IP. Let's say `192.168.1.133`. Was that issue by the WAP or router? If I connect directly to the router as an ethernet client on `eth2`, what's to stop the router from issuing the same IP? If I get a different IP, and want to `ssh` from the client on ethernet to the client on wireless, how is that managed? The router doesn't know there's a network connected to the client on `eth1`, and the WAP presumably doesn't know the router has a different client on `eth2`.

If it makes a difference I have an Ubiquity Edge Router X and an Ubiquity AP AC Lite. They're both setup with their most basic config options (e.g. logged in, went through default wizards, was good to go) and I never explicitly told them about each other.

Comment: I have a Ubiquiti Networks UAP-AC-LITE-US Dual-Radio Access Point.  It is simply a wireless Access Point on my network and not a DHCP server. It gets an address on the main network. That is what appears you got above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have some misconceptions about how Access Points and DHCP work.

Access Points work like Ethernet switches; they are transparent from L2 upwards. Since there’s stuff to configure (Wi-Fi network settings), you could say it’s more like a managed switch.

The AP does not act as a DHCP server. For ease of use, it can act as a DHCP client though.

DHCP servers have an “address pool”. Whenever a device requests an address, it is taken from this pool. The address is “leased”. The DHCP server keeps track of all active leases. It does not give out the same address twice. In fact, most DHCP servers have additional mechanisms to not accidentally give out addresses which are already in use by statically configuration hosts. And then, IP hosts usually also check whether an IP address already exists on the network before actually using it.

Making an IPv4 TCP connection to a wireless device works exactly the same way it does for wired targets: Learn the target’s MAC address using the ARP protocol, then start with sending SYN etc. Devices are just “on the local network”.

---

Update: DHCP is not magic. It is a normal network protocol that works on layers 2 upwards. Connecting to the wireless network is the same as connecting to a wired network. You wouldn’t expect the switch or the network cable to do anything special, right?

When you connect to a wireless network, it’s the same as connecting the network cable. You are then on the network. The end.

Now, usually you’d want IP connectivity, so that’s where DHCP comes into play. It uses the *existing network connection* to discover DHCP servers and asks them for an IP address, eventually taking one if all goes well.

Comment: Thanks this clears it up a bit. I think my misunderstanding still exists then but is more about how that DHCP works. Does the WAP tell the router "I have a new client connected to me, give me an IP I can use to refer to them with."? If the WAP does not act as a DHCP server, there must be some mechanism in place for it to query the router for DHCP. I understand DHCP from the router directly, but I think I'm getting confused around the WAP adding a level of indirection there.

Comment: The WAP has wireless settings to allow clients to access. You can see the clients in the WAP Controller client access table.  But the clients are just connected to the main network. I added this extra bit to my answer here.

Comment: @brenzo I’ve updated my answer. You still seem to think the AP is something special. It is not. Establishing a wireless link is a little more involved than Ethernet, but that’s all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screen shot of this Ubiquiti Access Point.  You can see in the Settings that there is no DHCP server.  So it is just a pure extension of your network with the main network doing DHCP.

[image]

Since the WAP is not a DHCP Server, it uses it Wireless Settings (it does have these) to allow any client with credentials access to the system via the Access Point. It does not tell the router anything (so far as I can see); merely provides access and the main network sees the access.  You can look in the WAP Controller and see the connected clients.